# Remove certain charcters from a text file and add them to a list

Tags: python

I have a text file like this:

```
polas:872147
skridd:142017
```

I want to convert it into a list like this:

```
['polas', '872147']
['skridd', '142017']
```

I tried using split function but it showed me error i.e.

```
f = open("user-id.txt", "r")
for user in enumerate(f):
    list = user.split(":")
    print(list)
```

Gives error as `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

Also if don't use `enumerate` the code works as expected but it's important for me to keep track of number of iterations.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue or any other alternative to get the desired result?

Comment: _"it's important for me to keep track of number of iterations"_ - but you're not _using_ that number, you're treating the tuple as if it was just a string. This is exactly what the error tells you. Also don't shadow `list`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "you are not using that number" sorry but why you guys expect us to share the whole code i can't share the whole code that's why am writing iteration no. is important and i also wrote i am accepting any alternative code that gives me the desired result not like only correcting the given code is mandatory for me

Comment: We expect you to give a [mre], per the [help]. We know you're not using the index in the whole code either because it's part of the tuple that for some reason you're assuming (despite the fact that you apparently _want_ the other value it provides, and explicitly _asked_ for it, which is the whole point of using enumerate, which is behaving exactly as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)) isn't a tuple. Read the error message, do some basic debugging!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `with` context manager for open file.
don't use the builtin `list` as a variable name.
with `enumerate` you can specify a variable `line_number` and starting number `start=1`.

```py
with open("user-id.txt", "r") as f:
    for line_number, user in enumerate(f, start=1):
        user_list = user.strip().split(":")
        print(line_number, user_list)
```

output:

```
1 ['polas', '872147']
2 ['skridd', '142017']
```

Answer (score -2):

**you use enumerate function notice that enumerate function give you you index and value both so it is so hard to read file using enumerate function.
So correct version is**:

```py
# first method 
print ("first method ")
with open("user.txt","r") as f:
    for data in f:
        print(data.split(":"))
print()
#2 method
print("2nd method ")
f=open ("user.txt","r")
d=f.readlines()
for data in d:
    print(data.split(":"))
```

[image: 1]
[image: 1]

Comment: Please, [do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)!